# Can anyone help me check my BMI Calculator? (C#)

Tags: c#, console, calculator

I just started programming a week ago and my first assignment was to code a BMI calculator.

It is supposed  to look like this when launched:

```
    BMI Calculator
    Your weight in kg: x 
    Your height in cm: x
    Gender (m/f): x

-> You are underweight/normal/overweight
```

Here is my code so far:

```
            Console.WriteLine("BMI Calculator");
            Console.WriteLine("===========");
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.Write("Weight in kg: ");
            int kg;
            kg = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Height in cm: ");
            int m;
            m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Gender (m/f):");
            string Geschlecht = Console.ReadLine();

            int BMI;
            BMI = kg / (m / 100) * (m / 100);

            if (BMI < 19 & Gender == "f")
            { Console.WriteLine("-> Underweight"); }
            if (BMI >= 19 & BMI <= 24 & Gender == "f") 
            { Console.WriteLine("-> Normal"); }
            if (BMI > 24 & Geschlecht == "f")
            { Console.WriteLine("-> Overweight"); }

            if (BMI < 20 & Gender == "m")
            { Console.WriteLine("-> Underweight"); }
            if (BMI >= 20 & BMI <= 25 & Gender == "m")
            { Console.WriteLine("-> Normal"); }
            if (BMI > 25 & Gendert == "m")
            { Console.WriteLine("-> Overweight"); }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with my code but whenever I enter 60kgs, 170cm and male, I get overweight, even though I should get normal. Same thing with anything above 10kgs actually.

PS: I'm really a beginner at programming so I apologize for my command of the programming lingo.

And for your convenience:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/admqr.png

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do:

```
BMI = kg / (m / 100) * (m / 100);
```

And `m` is an `int`, you'd be doing integer division, in which case `170 / 100 = 1`. And as User1551892 pointed out, you'll need to be a bit more specific about the order of calculations.

Try:

```
double BMI = kg / ( ( m / 100.0 ) * ( m / 100.0 ) );
```

That will force it to do floating point division and should get you better results.

Also, you could use `Math.Pow` to avoid having `m / 100.0` twice:

```
double BMI = kg / Math.Pow( m / 100.0, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check this line:

```
BMI = kg / (m / 100) * (m / 100);
```

it should be like this:

```
BMI = kg / ((m / 100) * (m / 100)) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI new stack's exchange portal has opened : [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

It should be better place to ask for review

Answer (score 1):

the calculation is off though for BMI. it is (weight/height)/height
so
int bmi = (kg/(m/100))/(m/100)

Answer (score 0):

Check Your gender's variable in each IF statement...